# JS Masonary not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to get Masonary to work on a page, and so far have had no luck. I've tried following a tutorial, but even when I copy everything in jsFiddle it doesn't work. Is there something stupid obvious that I'm missing here? ​http://jsfiddle.net/gZ77r/

```
<div id="container" class="js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 200, "itemSelector": ".masonryImage" }'>
    <div class="masonryImage">
        <img src="http://topknot.ca/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/kitten.jpg" alt="">
    </div>.....
```

`

Comment: what do you want to do exactly with all these photos and masonry.js? masonry.js is not a slider. http://tyler-designs.com/masonry-ui/

Comment: I want the images to list out like http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/masonry/demos/masonry.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your photos in the example came to conclusion that your image sizes are too big to use `masonry.js` . please check:

**http://jsfiddle.net/w4WrP/**

Answer (score 0):

Using Masonry with images requires using the imagesLoaded plugin, as Masonry can't know the height of a div without the image within the div being loaded.

Check the appendix for info on this: http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html

Add the images loaded plugin and try instantiating masonry via JS.

```
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  columnWidth: 200,
  itemSelector: '.masonryImage'
});
// layout Masonry again after all images have loaded
imagesLoaded( container, function() {
  msnry.layout();
});
```

Comment: Thanks zungaphobia, still no luck